# Portable encrypted container

Tags: gnome, encryption

I want to store some data encrypted to carry around with me (this includes some scans of relevant paperwork, my [TAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_authentication_numbers) List for online banking, my gnupg and ssh keys and stuff like that). So not really a *huge* amount of data but also more than a little textfile.

What I want is a container I can put on my thumbdrive to carry things around in that is fully encrypted. A few more requirements:

1. Strong Encryption, so no ZIP with passwords
2. I want to sync the container to more than one location (in case the thumbdrive breaks or is stolen for example) so I cannot just create another dmcrypt partition on the thumbdrive
3. I want to open the container from my GNOME environment without a lot of terminal fiddling. Not that I don't like terminals, but I want a certain level of convenience. (Right-clicking in nautilus to "mount" is OK, entering 3 commands in a terminal is not)
4. Bonus: Something I can open from Windows and/or OSX as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) ticks all of those boxes. You have the option of either encrypting the whole USB key, or just having an encrypted container (as a file)

It can then be decrypted regardless of platform, and can be configured to automount.

Comment: The one problem with Truecrypt I have is that it has a somewhat problematic license and that I don't know who builds it (trust issue). But I'll check out if things have changed in Truecrypt land.

Comment: @tante.. the really cool thing about truecrypt is the ease with which it mounts a encrypted.. and that its a platform independant sollution

Comment: truecrypt is no longer recommended by the truecrypt authors, and is no longer maintained.

Comment: Audit shows that TrueCrypt is probably OK http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2015/04/truecrypt-report.html

Answer (score 2):

> I want to sync the container to more than one location (in case the thumbdrive breaks or is stolen for example) so I cannot just create another dmcrypt partition on the thumbdrive

This requirement doesn't have to conflict with dm-crypt. You can create an encrypted file system *inside a file* like this:

```
# create 100M file
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 > somefile

# create loopback device backed by somefile
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 somefile

# create dm-crypt mapper device (prompts for passphrase)
sudo cryptsetup create encrypteddev /dev/loop0

# create filesystem
sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/mapper/encrypteddev

# mount filesystem
mkdir /home/user/encrypted
sudo mount /dev/mapper/encrypteddev /home/user/encrypted
```

> I want to open the container from my
>   GNOME environment without a lot of
>   terminal fiddling. Not that I don't
>   like terminals, but I want a certain
>   level of convenience. (Right-clicking
>   in nautilus to "mount" is OK, entering
>   3 commands in a terminal is not

You could create a mount and unmount script once, and then run those by clicking them. These scripts could be stored next to the encrypted file.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look to lastpass.com, it is browser based but you can export your vault to various password manager formats, and even in the browser is all client based (your password is not sent to the server, but the data is retrieved encrypted and decrypted in your browser). It does Firefox, Chrome and others so it is multiplatform, and it syncs the vault automatically across the computers where you are logged in to the vault with the master password.

It does automatic form filling too, and you can store notes as well.

Comment: You should never outsource your passwords.  http://blog.lastpass.com/2011/05/lastpass-security-notification.html